# Compiling MonoMac fails on Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: c#, macos, mono

Has anybody succeeded in compiling MonoMac from source, as downloaded from github at https://github.com/mono/monomac? I have both maccore and monomac downloaded but running make fails with:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Type 'System.Dynamic.BinaryOperationBinder' not found in assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
at IKVM.Reflection.Reader.ModuleReader.ResolveType (Int32 metadataToken, IGenericContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Mono compiler is 2.10.9.0 and XCode, assuming that is relevant, is 4.6.3. The current Mono Framework appears to be:

Current -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.1

which seems to be the latest version. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding a reference to 'System.Core' Version=3.5.0.0 if the reference is already there double check the version.